# User Input Shell Script Syntax Error

Tags: shell-script, shell, aircrack-ng

I'm new to shell scripts and all, and wanted to write a script that would automatically perform this command for me:

```
sudo aireplay-ng -0 (given number) -a (Router MAC Address) -c (Target MAC address) wlx000f60071636
```

The script would ask for user input, then perform the command with the input of the user.

So, I referenced these pages:

http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=deauthentication - For Aircrack Structure

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-shell-functions.htm - For designing functions which would allow for different numbers instead of -0, resulting in varied commands

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script - For user input

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-variables.htm - For Variables

And using these pages, I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ROUTER="(my router MAC)"
echo "Perform a wifi command?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) Deauth; break;;
        No ) exit;;
    esac
done

Deauth () {
    sudo airmon-ng start wlx000f60071636
    sudo airmon-ng check kill
    echo "Please specify device MAC:"
    read dmac
    echo "Number of commands to send, with 0 being unlimited:"
    read numts
    sudo aireplay-ng -0 $numts -a $ROUTER -c $dmac wlx000f60071636
}
```

However, after running

```
chmod +x wificommand.sh
```

and

```
sh wificommand.sh
```

I receive an error message of

```
wificommand.sh: 4: wificommand.sh: select: not found
wificommand.sh: 9: wificommand.sh: Syntax error: "done" unexpected
```

What is wrong with my code?  Is select unavailable to use?  Why should done not be there?  Is this the correct way to run a command with user input?

Comment: Perhaps because `sh` is not `bash` on your system? see for example [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` is a `bash` builtin, not a `sh` builtin.  Change your first line to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Changing the first line still results in an error message upon execution

Comment: @D4rKP01s0n if you are executing it as `sh wificommand.sh` that will override the "shebang" line and use `sh` anyway. Just execute it directly using the relative path `./wificommand.sh`

Comment: @steeldiver Thanks! That fixed that issue, and the rest I can figure out myself. Thank you!

Comment: @steeldiver Also, if you don't mind me asking, what is the proper way to call the function Deauth from inside the Yes case?

Comment: put the definitiion of `Deaith()` above the `select` stanza, and invoke with a simple `Deauth` (no parens) as you already have it.

Comment: `select` is a `ksh` builtin, bash just copied the idea.

Comment: My point was that it is explicitly _not_ a `sh` builtin.